# How to get full json response using httprequest

Tags: java, json, parsing, httprequest, httpresponse

Simply I am trying to hit URL i.e. www.google.com 
and I want to capture whole json responce as output ...
I tried multiple codes which help me to find only response code but I want full json response from which I can filter few information.

above thing  I am doing for web..

Comment: I didn't get precisely what you have to do: you want to transform http response into a json string or you want to capture only http responses wich are in json format?

Comment: Yes.. .while we hit any url , it responses interms of json response  , so I want to get these json response. ...

Comment: search for "how to send request with java"

Answer (score 0):

I used ApacheHttpClient jar (version 4.5.1). You'll also need HttpCore library (I used 4.4.3) and maybe some other apache libraries (like codec).

Here are a GET method and a POST method:

```
public static String getJsonStringHttpGet(String url,Map<String,String> headers) throws IOException {

        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
        .build();

        HttpCoreContext localContext = new HttpCoreContext();


        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);


        /*
         * if you need to specify headers
         */
        if (headers != null) {
            for (String name : headers.keySet()) {
                get.addHeader(name, headers.get(name));
            }
        }



        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get, localContext);



        byte [] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());


        return new String(bytes);

    }

public static String getJsonStringHttpPost(String url,Map<String,String> postParams,Map<String,String> headers) throws IOException {

        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
        .build();

        HttpCoreContext localContext = new HttpCoreContext();


        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        /*
         * adding some POST params
         */
        if (postParams != null && postParams.size() > 0) {

            List<BasicNameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String name : postParams.keySet()) {
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, postParams.get(name)));
            }

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
        }

        /*
         * if you need to specify headers
         */
        if (headers != null) {
            for (String name : headers.keySet()) {
                post.addHeader(name, headers.get(name));
            }
        }



        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post, localContext);



        byte [] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());


        return new String(bytes);

    }
```

Then you can parse the json string as you like.

Hope this helps